# extract "N" sized sequences from an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, performance, subset

Suppose I have the following array:

```
a <- sample(letters,100,replace=TRUE)
```

Then suppose those letters are ordered in a sequence, I want to extract all possible 'n' sized sequences from that array. For example:

For `n=2` I would do: `paste0(a[1:99],"->",a[2:100])`

for `n=3` I would do: `paste0(a[1:98],"->",a[2:99],"->",a[3:100])`

you get the point. Now, my goal is to create a function that would take as input `n` and would give me back the corresponding set of sequences of the given length from array `a`

I was able to do it using loops and all that but I was hoping for a high performance one liner.

I am a bit new to R so I'm not aware of all existing functions.

Comment: Try `embed(a, n)` ... obscure function with a weird name, but seems to do exactly this.

Comment: @Frank I thought It was not working at first but then I read the output starting from the last column and it was correct, I just need to figure out how to assemble each row starting from the last column to the first one and put them into one array

Comment: You can reverse the column order afterwards, like `embed(a, n)[, n:1]`

Comment: @Frank neat tricks. I will try an apply function to paste all rows separately then move them into a flat 1D array. Unless you have a better solution you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `embed`. For `embed(a, 3)`, this gives a matrix with columns

- `a[3:100]`
- `a[2:99]`
- `a[1:98]`

in that order.

To reverse the column order use matrix syntax `m[rows, cols]`:

```
res = embed(a, 3)[, 3:1]
```

If you want arrows printed between the columns, then

```
do.call(paste, c(split(res, col(res)), sep = " -> "))
```

is one way. This is probably better than `apply(res, 1, something)`, performance-wise, since this is vectorized while `apply` would loop over rows.

---

As pointed out by @DavidArenburg, this can similarly be done with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
do.call(paste, c(shift(a, 2:0), sep = " -> "))[-(1:2)]
```

`shift` is like `embed`, except it ...

- returns a list instead of a matrix, so we don't need to `split` by `col` to paste
- pads with missing values to keep the full length, so we need to drop with `-(1:2)`

---

I was hoping to say something useful about how to find obscure functions in R, but came up mostly blank on how `embed` might be found. Maybe...

1. Go to any HTML help page
2. Click the "Index" hyperlink at the bottom
3. Read every single page

?

Comment: Thanks @David , added